# Selection Sort not working

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, selection-sort

Here's my selection sort implementation using Java 1.7:

```
public class SelectionSort {

    private static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[j];
        a[j] = temp;
    }

    public static int[] sort(int[] numbers) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
            int smallestValue = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < numbers.length; j++) {
                if (numbers[j] < numbers[smallestValue])
                smallestValue = j;
            }
            swap(numbers, smallestValue, i);
        }
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

Inside my test harness, the following code is used to call the sort method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {    
    int[] unsortedNumbers = new int[] { 9, 8, 5, 4, 3, 7, 2, 1 };
    int[] sortedNumbers = new int[0];

    System.out.println("\nUnsorted Numbers:"); 
    if (unsortedNumbers.length >= 1) {
        System.out.print(unsortedNumbers[0]);
    } 

    for (int i=1; i <unsortedNumbers.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(", " + unsortedNumbers[i]);
    }

    sortedNumbers = SelectionSort.sort(unsortedNumbers);

    System.out.println("\n\nSorted Numbers:");

    if (sortedNumbers.length >= 1) {
        System.out.print(sortedNumbers[0]);
    }

    for (int j=1; j < sortedNumbers.length; j++) {
        System.out.print(", " + sortedNumbers.length);
    }
```

}

Here's the very frustrating / erroneous output:

```
Unsorted Numbers:
9, 8, 5, 4, 3, 7, 2, 1

Sorted Numbers:
1, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8
```

What am I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: You have a `;` at the end of your `if` statement.

Comment: Since, removing it didn't do anything different for the results - I am editing my post and removing it.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int j=1; j < sortedNumbers.length; j++) {
    System.out.print(", " + sortedNumbers.length);
}
```

Notice how you are printing the *length* of the array repeatedly, instead of the numbers in it.

You probably meant this:

```
for (int j=1; j < sortedNumbers.length; j++) {
    System.out.print(", " + sortedNumbers[j]);
}
```

Comment: I am such a dummy! Hahaha! Thanks immibis that was it!

Answer (score 1):

```
if (numbers[j] < numbers[smallestValue]);
smallestValue = j;
```

is the same as

```
if (numbers[j] < numbers[smallestValue])
    ;
smallestValue = j;
```

i.e. "If this number is less than the smallest number, do nothing. Then, set smallestValue to j." In Java (and C, and many other languages with syntax derived from C), `;` is a valid statement that does nothing.

Remove the extra semicolon.

Comment: immibis thank you! You have a good eye. But after removing it and surrounding the smallestValue = j with { } it still has the same value. Try copying and pasting my code and you see that it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Also you need additional `if` statements in your `sort` method:

```
if (smallestValue != i) {
    swap(numbers, smallestValue, i);
}
```

Use that code instead of:

```
swap(numbers, smallestValue, i);
```

Comment: Still doesn't work... Try copying and pasting using your suggestion and I guarantee it comes out wrong.

Comment: Swapping a number with itself won't break anything.

Comment: @socal_javaguy, you have a error in your main method, check it `for (int j = 1; j < sortedNumbers.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(", " + sortedNumbers[j]);
        }`

Comment: @immibis, check the references to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort)

Comment: @Beezy if you understand how the code works, you'll see why swapping a number with itself changes nothing, so the check is not required.